# Specs2 Steps not executing in order

Tags: scala, specs2

I am attempting to execute a Specification with multiple tests that all run within the same Play application and not a separate application for each test.

As such I have the following code which should print:

```
Play app started
[info] PlayRunningImmutableSpec
[info]     
[info]     + 200 status expected
[info]     
[info]     + 404 status expected
Play app stopped
```

but instead prints:

```
Play app started
Play app stopped
[info] PlayRunningImmutableSpec
[info]     
[info] 
[info]     ! 200 status expected
[error]  ConnectException: : Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:19001 to http://127.0.0.1:19001/
```

I am using Typesafe Activator 1.2.10 which includes Play 2.3.3 and Specs2 2.3.12

What is wrong with the following code, and what would work instead?

```
import org.specs2.Specification
import org.specs2.execute.Result
import org.specs2.specification.Step
import org.specs2.time.NoTimeConversions
import play.api.Play
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.http.{HeaderNames, HttpProtocol, Status}
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.test._

class PlayRunningImmutableSpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions with PlayRunners with HeaderNames with Status with HttpProtocol with DefaultAwaitTimeout with ResultExtractors with Writeables with RouteInvokers with FutureAwaits {

  override def is = s2"""
    ${Step(beforeAll)}

    200 status expected      $e1

    404 status expected      $e2

    ${Step(afterAll)}
  """

  def e1: Result = {
    await(WS.url(s"http://127.0.0.1:${Helpers.testServerPort}").get()).status === 200
  }

  def e2: Result = {
    await(WS.url(s"http://127.0.0.1:${Helpers.testServerPort}/missing").get()).status === 404
  }

  lazy val app = FakeApplication()

  private def beforeAll = {
    Play.start(app)
    println("Play app started")
  }

  private def afterAll = {
    Play.stop()
    println("Play app stopped")
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I realised my error was in the use the `play.api.Play.start` method and now have a simple trait to handle one startup and shutdown:

```
trait PlayServerRunning extends SpecificationLike {

  override def map(fs: => Fragments): Fragments = Step(beforeAll) ^ fs ^ Step(afterAll)

  private lazy val server = TestServer(Helpers.testServerPort)

  private def beforeAll = {
    server.start()
  }

  private def afterAll = {
    server.stop()
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's on propose. Tests are executed in parallel (with implementation details according execution context).

If your tests need to be sequential, you must annotate in this way. e.g.:

```scala
"X" should {
  sequential

  "exp1" in { ... }
  "exp2" in { ... }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for either a mutable or immutable Specification - the console output is unchanged (ie: connection refused)

Comment: Output is one thing, but may not reflect execution order. Where do you have put sequential?

Comment: Good point, however I tried it on the line before "override def is" as well as "${sequential}" on various lines within the interpolated "s2" String. The code snippet above can be used to prove this.